# pandas - get value based on another value in different data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe that holds all the stats for players in following manner

```
player_id   runs    balls_faced strike_rate name         match_date
4120         20          5        0.0       Aravind, S   2015-10-02
3788         10          10       0.0       Ashwin, R    2010-06-12
```

Based on this data frame I have created another data frame that aggreates and computes certain statistics through this code

```
player_data = dataFrame.groupby('player_id').aggregate({'runs': [np.sum,np.min,np.max,np.mean],
                                                        'strike_rate':'mean',
                                                        'player_id' : 'count'
                                                       }).reset_index()
player_data.columns = player_data.columns.get_level_values(0)
player_data.columns = ['player_id','total_runs','min_run','max_run','average','strike_rate','total_matches']
player_data.sort_values(['total_runs','average','strike_rate'], ascending=False)
```

The above code gives me following data frame

```
player_id   total_runs  min_run max_run average     strike_rate total_matches
4120            108      0        21    3.857143    54.568571       28
3788            1177     0        77    20.293103   103.391207      58
```

I need following as final output

```
Player_name player_id   total_runs  min_run max_run average     strike_rate total_matches
Aravind, S  4120            108      0        21    3.857143    54.568571       28
Ashwin, R   3788            1177     0        77    20.293103   103.391207      58
```

But due to group by other information such as Name of the player is lost. I need to retain that information. I have tried several things such as iloc or doing groupby with is_index = False but nothing seems to work.

The final solution I am working towards is create a data frame with just name and id and drop duplicates from them and then merge both the data frame on id but I feel that there must be some better or more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an aggregator function:

```
f = dict.fromkeys(dataFrame, 'first')
f.update({'runs': [np.sum,np.min,np.max,np.mean],
          'strike_rate':'mean',
          'player_id' : 'count'
})
```

Now, pass `f` to player_data:

```
player_data = dataFrame.groupby('player_id').aggregate(f)
```

The idea here is to have everything you don't want lost aggregated as having the first value from the original group of values.

In the case of "Name", every value is the same (AKA, the player name), so taking just the first value makes sense in theory.

---

Another method, if it's just the Name column you want added in (and nothing else), you can build a mapping of player_ids to Names, and then manually add in your column of Names to the result.

```
mapping = dict(zip(dataFrame.player_id, dataFrame.name))
...    
player_data['name'] = player_data['player_id'].map(mapping)
```

Comment: Thanks coldspeed for solution it works perfectly but the code I had to rename columns and remove the hierarcy no longer works. player_data.columns = player_data.columns.get_level_values(0)
player_data.columns = ['player_id','total_runs','min_run','max_run','average','strike_rate','total_matches','name','match_date']   ... Any way to retain that ??

Comment: Also can you also explain the first solution a bit as I am new to pandas so not able to grasp fully on that.

Comment: @Neel I think the problem is your `'player_id' : 'count'`, player_id is present in the index AND the column, as an aggregated column. You may want to change `'player_id' : 'count'` to {<some other column> : `count`}, and then before you call agg, do `del f['player_id']` and see how that works.

Comment: @Neel The first solution specifies that you take the _first_ value from all groups unless otherwise explicitly specified. This includes columns like "Name" where it theoretically makes sense to do so. This is a good option for columns that cannot be aggregated and yet you want them retained in the result anyway.

Comment: thanks for the explanation as I only wanted to retain the player name so went with the second option